# Flutter how can i use for loop to get past 15 date?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to run my api and it will hit 15 times because date in APIs are different and past 15 days. I need to know how can i use for loop to get past 15 days date?

My api look like this

```
https://api?start=2021-03-19&end=2021-03-20
```

You can see in end date I have today date and in start 1-day the previous date.

What I need to do is use for loop to run this api with date of 15 days.

It will look like this I think

```
for(some thing i get date) {
 https://api?start=2021-03-19&end=2021-03-20
 https://api?start=2021-03-18&end=2021-03-19
 https://api?start=2021-03-17&end=2021-03-18
 https://api?start=2021-03-16&end=2021-03-17
 https://api?start=2021-03-15&end=2021-03-16
 https://api?start=2021-03-14&end=2021-03-15
 https://api?start=2021-03-13&end=2021-03-14
 https://api?start=2021-03-12&end=2021-03-13
 https://api?start=2021-03-11&end=2021-03-12
 https://api?start=2021-03-10&end=2021-03-11
 https://api?start=2021-03-9&end=2021-03-10
 https://api?start=2021-03-8&end=2021-03-9
 https://api?start=2021-03-7&end=2021-03-8
 https://api?start=2021-03-6&end=2021-03-7
 https://api?start=2021-03-5&end=2021-03-6
 https://api?start=2021-03-4&end=2021-03-5
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```dart
void main() {

  // initial dates 
  var toDate = DateTime.now().toUtc(); // see note below
  var fromDate = toDate.subtract(Duration(days: 1));
  for (var i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
    // put them into a string
    final fromDateString = '${fromDate.year}-${fromDate.month.toString().padLeft(2,'0')}-${fromDate.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
    final toDateString = '${toDate.year}-${toDate.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${toDate.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
    // buld the url
    final url = 'https://api?start=$fromDateString&end=$toDateString';
    print(url);
    // update the dates for the next loop
    fromDate = fromDate.subtract(Duration(days: 1));
    toDate = toDate.subtract(Duration(days: 1));
  }
}

// prints: 
// https://api?start=2021-03-19&end=2021-03-20
// https://api?start=2021-03-18&end=2021-03-19
// https://api?start=2021-03-17&end=2021-03-18
// https://api?start=2021-03-16&end=2021-03-17
// https://api?start=2021-03-15&end=2021-03-16
// https://api?start=2021-03-14&end=2021-03-15
// https://api?start=2021-03-13&end=2021-03-14
// https://api?start=2021-03-12&end=2021-03-13
// https://api?start=2021-03-11&end=2021-03-12
// https://api?start=2021-03-10&end=2021-03-11
// https://api?start=2021-03-09&end=2021-03-10
// https://api?start=2021-03-08&end=2021-03-09
// https://api?start=2021-03-07&end=2021-03-08
// https://api?start=2021-03-06&end=2021-03-07
// https://api?start=2021-03-05&end=2021-03-06
// https://api?start=2021-03-04&end=2021-03-05
```

========== **Note:**

As @RandalSchwartz mentioned in the comments, it's advisable to use UTC time to avoid incorrect result in certain cases, to quote:

> Best to do this with UTC, not localtime, because adding and subtracting a day might run into trouble when crossing a DST boundary (or is it just 24 hours that has trouble?) EDIT: From Duration: "Durations are context independent. For example, a duration of 2 days is always 48 hours, even when it is added to a DateTime just when the time zone is about to do a daylight-savings switch. (See DateTime.add)." Yeah, dangerous to add 24 hours to a localtime. Use GMT.

> Notice that the duration being added is actually 50 * 24 * 60 * 60 seconds. If the resulting DateTime has a different daylight saving offset than this, then the result won't have the same time-of-day as this, and may not even hit the calendar date 50 days later. Be careful when working with dates in local time.

> ref: https://api.dart.dev/be/169657/dart-core/DateTime/add.html:

if desired, the `DateTime` can be converted back to local using `.toLocal();` method of the `DateTime` class.

Comment: Thank you so.  Can you tell how can i add current date in DateTime and -1 date so it will show today date and one day before ? Thanks again for your help

Comment: @rameezkhan You can use` DateTime.now()` to get the current date and then just do the same. So `toDate = DateTime.now()` and `fromDate = toDate.subtract(Duration(days:1))`

Comment: @rameezkhan I updated the answer with today's date and 15 days back

Comment: Best to do this with UTC, not localtime, because adding and subtracting a day might run into trouble when crossing a DST boundary (or is it just 24 hours that has trouble?) EDIT: From Duration: "Durations are context independent. For example, a duration of 2 days is always 48 hours, even when it is added to a DateTime just when the time zone is about to do a daylight-savings switch. (See DateTime.add)."  Yeah, dangerous to add 24 hours to a localtime.  Use GMT.

Comment: https://api.dart.dev/be/169657/dart-core/DateTime/add.html: Notice that the duration being added is actually 50 * 24 * 60 * 60 seconds. If the resulting DateTime has a different daylight saving offset than this, then the result won't have the same time-of-day as this, and may not even hit the calendar date 50 days later.

Be careful when working with dates in local time.

Comment: Thank you @RandalSchwartz, you brought a good point. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Here's my screencast inspired by this question: https://youtu.be/usFSVUEadyo

Comment: To address the daylight savings time issue with adding dates, use an extension to the DateTime class like this.

`extension DateTimeExtension on DateTime { DateTime safeAddDays(int days) { return DateTime(year, month, day+days); } }` 

You can run the example jdoodle to show why it is needed. The example crosses the 11/3/2024 daylight savings time.

https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/Wu3

Answer (score 1):

So you need to call your api request 15 times and the dates should be decreased by 1 on each step right? Here is an example but you need [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) to format the DateTime.

```
  // Parse date without timestamp
  final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');

  final DateTime today = DateTime.now();

  for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    // Get start date
    final DateTime startDate = today.subtract(Duration(days: i + 1));

    // Parse as string
    final String start = formatter.format(startDate);

    // Get end date
    final DateTime endDate = today.subtract(Duration(days: i));

    // Parse as string
    final String end = formatter.format(endDate);

    final String apiUrl = 'https://api?start=$start&end=$end';
}
```